# Number of paths of size 1xn

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Full question:

> Suppose there are $1\times1$ tiles of the same color, and $1\times2$ tiles in $12$ different colors. Write the recurrence relation with initial conditions for the number of ways to pave a path of the size $1\times n$. Next, provide the solution

I believe the recursion is $a(n) = a(n-1) + 12a(n-2)$.

I had initial conditions as $a(0)=1, a(1)=1, a(2)=13$.

My final answer, after solving using the general solution, was $a(n) = x_1(-3)^n+ x_2(4)^n$ where $x_1$ was $9/21$. I forget $x_2$.

Is this the correct way to solve this problem? Did I make any errors?

Comment: $9/21=3/7,$ and you must have $x_2=4/7$ to make $n=0$ work, assuming your computation of $x_1$ is correct.

Comment: What is $a(1)$?

Comment: You also only need initial conditions for $n=0,1.$

Comment: @theo a(1)=1. Typo on my part

Answer (score 1):

This is fine.  I didn't check $x_1, x_2$

Comment: It looks like $(x_1,x_2)=(3/7,4/7)$ is correct.

Comment: Awesome. And my bad, I meant to have a(1)=1, not ?. And ivgot 3/7 and 4/7. Thanks yall.